# styled checkboxes overlap in table

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I got this snippet from another question here on stackoverflow:

[Snippet](http://jsbin.com/edipux/3/edit?html,css,output)

If I put these checkboxes in a table, one checkbox per row, they overlap due to the padding of the labels. Why does this happen? Why doesn't the table cells change their height?

And how can I fix it?

Also, 'width: 100%' does not work for the label

Comment: Have you tried using pixels instead of percentage? Maybe height instead of width?

Comment: Try adding overflow:hidden to the CSS of the containing element. That will kill the overlap.

Comment: I can adjust the height of the `td`-element manually, of course. But I think this should happen automatically. And the width of the label does not work with pixels either

Comment: @Sleek Geek: did not work and even if it did, the border would be cut off at the top and bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
tr {
display:block;
margin:10px 0px;
}
```

Or without adding table styles

```
label{
display: block;
}
```

Also, I made a codepen [here](http://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: `display:block;` did it for me. Thanks!