# Label text overlapping radio button

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Only on an iPhone 5 (on all other screens this looks fine) I am having trouble with the text of this label overlapping the radio button:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
    <input type="radio" id="qMCa" value="TextMessage"><label for="qMCa"><span></span>Text Message</label>
</div>
```

And here's the css for `label`

```
label {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is how it looks on the iPhone 5:

[image]

If I change`display` to `block` for the label, I get this:

[image]

The text needs to line up, and it needs to not overlap the radio button.  I've been looking at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745605/checkbox-label-overlapping-the-checkbox-bootstrap3), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27788308/styled-checkboxes-overlap-in-table), but so far have not been able to nail it.

Comment: try giving whitespace:nowrap; for that span by <span>Text Message</span>

Comment: Have you tried display: inline-block; on the label instead of flex?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal ha HA!  I honestly don't know why I didn't think of that!  Make it an answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @KyleSposato, I did, and it gave the same results as the first screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving whitespace:nowrap; to avoid the text split up ,for that span by Text Message

Answer (score 0):

Change display property, Try this

```
display: inline;
```